# "/usr/bin/python" missing after installing Python 3.0

Tags: python

OS version:Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Hey all, I recently started programming in python, so I went to download python 3.0, and it appears I have ruined all python files on my installation, whenever I try to run anything with python I get this error:

```
chris@chris-Modena-M101:~$ python
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
chris@chris-Modena-M101:~$
```

I tried to install Python 3 again it said it was done, but I still get this error. Please can anyone help me? This is really bugging me as I cant use many defalt ubuntu programs because of this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you happen to remove the python2 packages? The python3 packages do not touch /usr/bin/python at all. Perhaps you just need to re-run dpkg-reconfigure python*.

Comment: I am not sure,i think i did remove the python2 packages,by accident of course,i am not going to lie i am a bit of a noob on linux,but i am learning.I ran the command "dkpg-reconfigure python" and it returned the same error :(

Answer (score 5):

You don't run python3 by running `python`.  You run it by running `python3` or `python3.2` at this time.

If you removed python2/2.7, then you shouldn't have a /usr/bin/python.  Don't remove python2.  They happily co-exist.

If you want `python` the command back:

1. `apt-get -f --reinstall install python python-minimal python2.7 python-doc python-tk`
2. alias `python` to `python3`
   or
3. softlink `python` to `python3`

The preferred method would be to reinstall the python pseudo-package.

note: python doesn't appear to be integrated into update-alternatives... I just checked.

Comment: Ah thankyou! python3 is installed :D!how would i go about re install python 2.x then? as ubntu software center wont start since i rmoved the old python :/

Comment: chris@chris-Modena-M101:~$ sudo apt-get -f reinstall python

[sudo] password for chris: 

E: Invalid operation reinstall

chris@chris-Modena-M101:~$


I get this error :/

Comment: Just tried /sigh* now this:


chris@chris-Modena-M101:~$ sudo apt-get -f install python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jockey-gtk : Depends: jockey-common (= 0.9.7-0ubuntu7.1) but 0.9.7-0ubuntu7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
chris@chris-Modena-M101:~$

Comment: ignore this was a dupe message

Comment: You're not running stock 12.04 or you did something strange like run an edgers ppa that broke things.

Comment: Sorry,but what is stock 12.04? and i dont even know what an edgers PPA is xD-sorry for being a noob :(

Comment: it apears sudo apt-get install is broken,wont work at all

Comment: `python` should start python2.x and `python3` – python3.x executables otherwise tools that expect python to refer to 2.x version might break

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Very fair point.  Anything that relied on python being in /usr/bin/env should already have broken (which is a lot).  So it was odd the question was even asked